# How to set minimum supported iOS version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

All my iOS build targets are:
`IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 14.0;`

but it's saying I'm supporting 9.0. Am I misunderstanding something?

Error:

`The package product 'Crypto' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 9.0`

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. @EricHua

Comment: Might be an issue with the package. I ran into some stuff like this when iOS 14 rolled out using firebase and FBSDK

Comment: Have you specified the version in your `Package.swift`? If yes, please show us your Package.swift file

Comment: That might be what I'm misunderstanding (excuse my xcode/swift noobiness) but it's an xcode 12 project, not swift. I just imported the packages via xcode. (No package.swift). iOS version is specified in xcode itself. @CanhTran

Answer (score 23):

## Platforms!

You have to add the **platforms** section to your *Package.swift* file like line below:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v12),
        .tvOS(.v12),
        .watchOS(.v5),
        .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
```

That's the **usual case** to cause this error.

Best.

Comment: [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7043401/nick), Please check my answer, and don't hesitate to mark it as the Correct Answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove that package and add it again.
Find your suitable version/branch of your package in github and edit in here.

[image: Ex: Adding Alamofire]

Comment: Yeah... but I need the upstream main package. And the main package is including the dependency packages that are causing this error.

Comment: It seems like a bug for it to say I support a minimum iOS version 9.0 when my deployment target is 14.0. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest part would be to just change the iOS deployment target to your new minimum iOS version.

You can do this by selecting Project Target in Xcode -> General -> Deployment Info -> Here you can change Deployment Target.

You can follow this link for detailed information:-

https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/minimum-ios-version/

Comment: That's what I did to set it to 14.0